# Get user IP via comment Form

Tags: php, mysql

I have inserted a hidden input in my comment form:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
<input type="hidden" name="c-ip" value="<?php echo $ip; ?>">
```

Query :

```
$cname = removeXSS(mysql_real_escape_string($_post['c-name']));
.
.
.
$sql = "INSERT INTO guestbook (id, date, name, email, comment, ip, status) VALUES (' ', NOW(), '$cname', '$cemail', '$ctext' , '$cip', ' ') ";

function RemoveXSS($val) {
 // remove all non-printable characters. CR(0a) and LF(0b) and TAB(9) are allowed
 // this prevents some character re-spacing such as <java\0script>
 // note that you have to handle splits with \n, \r, and \t later since they *are*   allowed in some inputs
 $val = preg_replace('/([\x00-\x08,\x0b-\x0c,\x0e-\x19])/', '', $val);

// straight replacements, the user should never need these since they're normal characters
// this prevents like <IMG SRC=&#X40&#X61&#X76&#X61&#X73&#X63&#X72&#X69&#X70&#X74&#X3A &#X61&#X6C&#X65&#X72&#X74&#X28&#X27&#X58&#X53&#X53&#X27&#X29>
$search = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$search .= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$search .= '1234567890!@#$%^&*()';
$search .= '~`";:?+/={}[]-_|\'\\';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($search); $i++) {
  // ;? matches the ;, which is optional
  // 0{0,7} matches any padded zeros, which are optional and go up to 8 chars

  // &#x0040 @ search for the hex values
  $val = preg_replace('/(&#[xX]0{0,8}'.dechex(ord($search[$i])).';?)/i', $search[$i], $val); // with a ;
  // &#00064 @ 0{0,7} matches '0' zero to seven times
  $val = preg_replace('/(&#0{0,8}'.ord($search[$i]).';?)/', $search[$i], $val); // with a ;
}


$ra1 = Array('javascript', 'vbscript', 'expression', 'applet', 'meta', 'xml', 'blink', 'link', 'style', 'script', 'embed', 'object', 'iframe', 'frame', 'frameset', 'ilayer', 'layer', 'bgsound', 'title', 'base');
$ra2 = Array('onabort', 'onactivate', 'onafterprint', 'onafterupdate', 'onbeforeactivate', 'onbeforecopy', 'onbeforecut', 'onbeforedeactivate', 'onbeforeeditfocus', 'onbeforepaste', 'onbeforeprint', 'onbeforeunload', 'onbeforeupdate', 'onblur', 'onbounce', 'oncellchange', 'onchange', 'onclick', 'oncontextmenu', 'oncontrolselect', 'oncopy', 'oncut', 'ondataavailable', 'ondatasetchanged', 'ondatasetcomplete', 'ondblclick', 'ondeactivate', 'ondrag', 'ondragend', 'ondragenter', 'ondragleave', 'ondragover', 'ondragstart', 'ondrop', 'onerror', 'onerrorupdate', 'onfilterchange', 'onfinish', 'onfocus', 'onfocusin', 'onfocusout', 'onhelp', 'onkeydown', 'onkeypress', 'onkeyup', 'onlayoutcomplete', 'onload', 'onlosecapture', 'onmousedown', 'onmouseenter', 'onmouseleave', 'onmousemove', 'onmouseout', 'onmouseover', 'onmouseup', 'onmousewheel', 'onmove', 'onmoveend', 'onmovestart', 'onpaste', 'onpropertychange', 'onreadystatechange', 'onreset', 'onresize', 'onresizeend', 'onresizestart', 'onrowenter', 'onrowexit', 'onrowsdelete', 'onrowsinserted', 'onscroll', 'onselect', 'onselectionchange', 'onselectstart', 'onstart', 'onstop', 'onsubmit', 'onunload');
$ra = array_merge($ra1, $ra2);

$found = true; // keep replacing as long as the previous round replaced something
while ($found == true) {
  $val_before = $val;
  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ra); $i++) {
     $pattern = '/';
     for ($j = 0; $j < strlen($ra[$i]); $j++) {
        if ($j > 0) {
           $pattern .= '(';
           $pattern .= '(&#[xX]0{0,8}([9ab]);)';
           $pattern .= '|';
           $pattern .= '|(&#0{0,8}([9|10|13]);)';
           $pattern .= ')*';
        }
        $pattern .= $ra[$i][$j];
     }
     $pattern .= '/i';
     $replacement = substr($ra[$i], 0, 2).'<x>'.substr($ra[$i], 2); // add in <> to nerf the tag
     $val = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $val); // filter out the hex tags
     if ($val_before == $val) {
        // no replacements were made, so exit the loop
        $found = false;
     }
  }
}
return $val;
```

}

With this input, ip column is empty in mysql. What is wrong in input.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and add the MySQL code as well; the code you posted seems fine.

Comment: You will need to show how you import the field into mySQL. But storing the IP address like this is dangerously stupid: An attacker could change it freely. You should fetch `REMOTE_ADDR` in the script you make the SQL query in.

Comment: Why do you have to get it from an input field? It's more hackable than the REMOTE_ADDR. Just store the REMOTE_ADDR when posting.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` - add this command at the top of your code that runs an insert query and see what it say

Comment: @ZZ Coder 
I want to see commentator's IP in admin panel.

Comment: You always have IP available in PHP as $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. Just save that to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you reading it back, are you trying this:

```
echo $_POST['c-ip'];
```

and make sure that you are using correct super global variable based on the `method` attribute of your form.

You might want to see though your array to check if IP is coming though from the hidden field:

```
var_dump ($_POST);
```

OR

```
var_dump ($_REQUEST); // not a good idea though
```

**Update**

You could simply try this too:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO guestbook (id, date, name, email, comment, ip, status) VALUES (' ', NOW(), '$cname', '$cemail', '$ctext' , '$ip', ' ') ";
```

You see there is no need to save the IP in a hidden field and store it later on, you can get it anytime from PHP's super global array.

Comment: Hi Sarfraz;
With echo $ip in form, I have correct value of IP
["c-ip"]=>  string(13) "87.239.19.109"

Comment: @jasmine: how are you constructing the variable `$cip` in your sql query? What are you assigning to this variable?

Comment: Are there SQL injection issues here assuming that $cname and $cemail are coming straight from the form or will PHP take card of sanitising them somehow?

Comment: @jasmine: would you post the `removeXSS` function in your question also to see exactly what it is doing. Thanks

Comment: @Martin Smith ;
Its only for sender's IP, But I have to find solution for proxy.

Comment: @jasmine: yes using only IP is not the way to go, you will have to find an alternative to that and if i can remember i had seen a solution here at SO but can't remember where but you can search it. Thanks

Comment: There is a solution here:
http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/getting-real-ip-address-in-php.html
and
http://www.oxyscripts.com/itemdisplay.php?id=1059&code=yes

Answer (score 0):

The whole approach is wrong.
I have no idea why did you put an IP address into form field.
And I don't understand why you starting to talk of inserting an IP addres into **HTML form** and then continue with complaining it weren't inserted into **SQL database**.  These are different tasks.
You have to make your mind up first.

Why not to add the IP address right before query execution?

Answer (score 0):

In the form you have 'c-ip', but when inserting it into the database it's 'cip'.  Are you manipulating it in between, or is this a typo.

It that's correct, what type is the 'ip' field in the guestbook table?

But as the others said, much better not to have it in the form in the first place.